# UIDocumentMenuViewController showing single browse option

Tags: ios, swift, import, uidocumentmenuviewcontroller

I try to import files to my app via the following code:

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeData)], in: .import)
        importMenu.delegate = self
        importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        importMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It shows just the browse option, although I have Google Drive and Dropbox apps installed.

[image]

When i tap browse, it opens Files app browser and I can choose the cloud drives, but i want them to be presented above the browse option like so:

[image]

How can I achieve that?